# Check convergence /divergence of a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(n)^{\frac{1}{4}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n-1}}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}} )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> for $(a)$ and $(b)$ decide if the series converges , converges conditionally or diverge

$(a)$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(n)^{\frac{1}{4}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n-1}}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}} )$

$(b)\ $ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(n)^{\frac{5}{4}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n-1}}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{4n}} )$

i tried to use Leibniz test for $(a)$ and $(b)$ but failed.
i tried to do assymptotic tests but failed.

also i am not sure how to decide if the sequence monotonically decreasing

Comment: First series is absolutely convergent. Compare with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{5/4}}$.

Comment: but i can't compare since its not positive series

Comment: i know i tried with the absolute values but the lim is $ \infty - \infty $ how to calculate it i am trying lophital too

Comment: devide by $\frac{1}{ n^{ \frac{5}{4} } }$ the lim is unclear

Comment: For (a), Sum is equal to integral: $\frac{\int_0^{\infty } \frac{-1+\, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{4};\frac{x}{4}\right)}{\left(1+e^x\right) x^{3/4}} \, dx}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\approx 0.0585087$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to first series: $\frac 1 {\sqrt {(4n-1)}}- \frac 1 {\sqrt {4n}} =\frac  {\sqrt {4n}-\sqrt {4n-1}} {\sqrt {4n-1} \sqrt {4n}}$. Write this as $\frac  1 {\sqrt {4n-1} \sqrt {4n}(\sqrt {4n}+\sqrt {4n-1})}$. Note that the denominator is of the order of $n^{3/2}$. Apply comparison test now (Note that $\frac 3 2-\frac 1 4=\frac 5 4 >1)$. Hence the first series is absolutely convergent. A similar argument shows that the second series is not absolutely convergent. Try to prove its convergence using Alternating Series Test.

Comment: thank you sir , much clear now